# Function not loaded on EventListener "load"

Tags: javascript, load

I have a `.txt` file called `sample.txt`, where I want to load some text and display it into my HTML document.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("load", getText);
console.log("script loaded succesfully")
function getText(){
  fetch('sample.txt').then(function(data){
    console.log("hello")
    console.log(data.text);
  });
}
```

My issue is that the function `getText`, is not called on load, how can this be, when it logs out script loaded successfully?

Comment: `load` event doesn't fire for regular elements. It's for `window` object.

Comment: There are load events on plenty of elements including `img` and `iframe`, i.e. elements which trigger the *load* of external content. Divs don't load anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to call the `load` event it by attaching it to the `window` like :

```
window.addEventListener("load", getText);
```

I think to be sure that the DOM is loaded you could use `DOMContentLoaded` event instead :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getText);
```

Comment: He needs to listen when a file is loaded, not when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I don't think so @ConstantinChirila

Comment: @ConstantinChirila did you just assume my gender?

Comment: I think @ZakariaAcharki is right because the "addEventListener" need to add the listener event first load and only at the second time to active the getText() function

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm kinda new to javascript and I was wondering would the DOMContentLoaded also work if where to put my script at the end of my body? Because wouldn't the DOM then already be loaded before the evenlistener is added and never trigger? (this is a hypothetical question I always put my scripts in the header but I was just wondering)

Comment: Hi @mrdeadsven _would the DOMContentLoaded also work if where to put my script at the end of my body?_ Yes it will work, but it may not necessary is such cases...